# How to get Configuration SharePoint Database Server using Power-Shell?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have X number of database servers on the farm , I need to know

Which database server have the SharePoint Configuration Database using Power-Shell ?

I know I can get Which server via Central Administration by Navigating to

> System Settings > Servers on Farm

But I need to get SharePoint Configuration Database server via Power Shell ,

Is there a cmdlet to achieve that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming a setup close to the defaults (and that you already loaded the SharePoint snapin via `asnp *sh*`), I would try this:

```
$server = (Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.name -like "SharePoint_Config"})[0].Server
$server
```

Answer (score 10):

Select database by type, and ask for the server. Like this:

```
$ConfigDB = Get-SPDatabase | Where-Object{$_.Type -eq "Configuration Database"}
$ConfigDB.server
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = Get-SPDatabase | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -like '*config*'}
Write-Host $a.Server
```

Works on: Sharepoint 2019 + Windows 2019